# Twilio SDK voip call Invalid Uri

Tags: ios, objective-c, twilio, voip

When I tried to make a call "name" to "name" via twilio I had this error :

> pjsua_call.c  .Dialog creation failed: Invalid URI (PJSIP_EINVALIDURI)

As I followed the twilio tutorial I have no idea why this error happen.
Any clue ?

Here the way I got the token (should be ok)

```
 - (void)getTwilioToken{

        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://foo.herokuapp.com/token?client=%@", [[[Utils getUserCredential] componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"] objectAtIndex:1]];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *token = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

        if(token == nil){
            NSLog(@"Error retrieving token: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            _phone = [[TCDevice alloc] initWithCapabilityToken:token delegate:self];
        }

    }
```

Here the code used to make the call :

```
-(IBAction)callResponder:(id)sender{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];

    NSString *responderEmail = [[self.responders objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] email];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"To": responderEmail};

    //check if we can make an outgoing call and attempt a connection
    NSNumber* hasOutgoing = [_phone.capabilities objectForKey:TCDeviceCapabilityOutgoingKey];
    if ( [hasOutgoing boolValue] == YES ){

        //Disconnect if we've already got a connection in progress
        if(_connection){
            [_connection disconnect];
        }
         _connection = [_phone connect:params delegate:self];
        [_connection retain];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this same issue myself. The problem pertained to how I set permissions for the Twilio token (using their Javascript API):

```
var capability = new twilio.Capability(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);

capability.allowClientOutgoing(twilioAppSid);
capability.allowClientIncoming(); // this is the problematic line
```

After I removed the (apparently incorrect) incoming permission setting line my device completed the call perfectly.